# Find out where memory is being eaten up using ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

I am running a mediaWiki page and I can no longer log in and we suspected that it is because it has 0 memory, we restarted the server and now the site isnt up and we believe it is the same cause. I dont know linux enough to be able to look for where the memory is going and how I can see these files to see if they are relevant or not so I can delete them to free up space. Here is a screen shot of what I have done so far. from what i see it says 17G out of 17G is being used. but where? the listings below dont add up anywhere near 17G.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of memory. It's a disk space problem: your root partition is full! Strange enough most of the root partition storage is used for the /etc directory. I would suggest you to have a closer look into `/etc` with `du -s` to find what the disk space is used to.

`/etc` should just contain configuration and startup scripts; NOT logs or so...

Comment: after running du -s, i got 16615928. seems 16G is being used correct? i ran ls -lah and it says total 796k and a description of all the  objects in there with corresponding size

Comment: Yes, you should now.... `cd /etc ; du -s *` and find where where most of the space is used. If it's a directory then `cd <that directory> ; du -s *` again and so on until you find the file or group of files using most of the space. When you will find the file(s) using most of your root partition it should be easy to find what/why produce them...